# How do I execute an insert command on a table in a different root?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am extracting image chips of blobs detected from a bunch of images and storing this data to an sqlite3 database for later use.

I am successfully able to filter the images, find the blobs, extract an image chip of the blobs, and store the filename, blob center coordinates, and blob chip data to a database that is in the same directory as my code.

```
def addEntry(filename, cp_y, cp_x, sigma, intensity, chip):
    sqlite3.register_adapter(np.ndarray, adapt_array)
    sqlite3.register_converter('ARRAY', convert_array)
    con = sqlite3.connect('sources.db', detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout = 10)
    cur = con.sursor()
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO sources (filename, cp_y, cp_x, sigma, intensity, chip) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?), (filename, cp_y, cp_x, sigma, intensity, chip))
    con.commit()
    con.close()
```

Now I want to implement this over a couple hundred images and create a different table for each images extracted data.  I would like to store these tables in a folder separate from my other code so I changed my code to:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('./data/sources.db', detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout = 10)
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO ./data/sources (filename, ...
```

But this returned the error `OperationalError: near ".": syntax error`.  But if I remove the `./data/` portion in the execute command, I receive the error `OperationalError: no such table: sources`.  How do I define the `sources` table in the `/data/` folder to the `INSERT` command ??

The documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) does not show an example of executing a command on a table in a different directory and I am yet to come across any other examples of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You expect sqlite to replace the `.` by the current folder path. But it doesn't provide this feature. You can instead provide the full path

```
import os
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
DB_PATH = SCRIPT_DIR +  '/data/sources.db'
...
con = sqlite3.connect(DB_PATH, detect_types = sqlite3.PARSE_DECLTYPES, timeout = 10)
```

If the file/table did not exist before, you should simply perfom a kind of database initilization to create the table. But this would be nothing more than the `CREATE TABLE` statement

```
CREATE TABLE sources (...) VALUES ();
```

Comment: This solved my problem.  I had no idea that the `./` was not recognized as the current folder path b/c the `sqlite3.connect` command did not return any errors. But the `INSERT INTO sources` was unable to resolve that `sources` was in the directory that was currently connected so I assumed this was where my problem was.